# MYSQL: DATE function returning null in Select query

Tags: mysql

i have a data with all column types as `text` even date also stored in text type column. Now when i am using `select` query to access the column its working find but when i am trying to perform any date operation on that column it always return null.

Table:

[image]

if am running query `select column_14 from mytable where id = 2` its working fine but when i am trying to find the difference between today date and `column_14` its always return `null`

**Query Running:**

```
select DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE(column_14,"%y-%m-%d")) from `mytable` where id = 2
```

[image]

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my query ?

**Structure View**

[image]

Comment: Use this, DATEDIFF(NOW(),DATE(column_14))

Comment: same result.....

Comment: your date column have y-m-d format, so try once like, DATEDIFF(NOW(),column_14)  without DATE().

Comment: is there any effect if my table have `Engine=MyISAM`?

Comment: i got the problem..there is mistake in my data. I just export a single row and its have `\0` with date and after `REPLACE` that i am able to perform date operations..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `%Y` instead of `%y.` `%Y` takes 4 digit year.

`DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE(column_14,"%Y-%m-%d")`)

Comment: i agree with you but it always returns null

Comment: even if i am using simple `date()` it returns `null`

Comment: its just a header

Comment: Can you update the question to show the whole row including id = 2.

Comment: A simple `select DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE('2010-10-11','%Y-%m-%d'));` gives proper date difference, must be something to do with the table or table name. Rest all seems to be fine.

Comment: my table engine is `myisam`

Comment: i got the problem..there is mistake in my data. I just export a single row and its have `\0` with date and after `REPLACE` that i am able to perform date operations..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Str_to_date will return null values if you pick the wrong format or the function detects an out of range month or day number. In your example you have picked a wrong format %y should be %Y. Here are some samples of what can happen. (nb: str_to_date is poor at this and doesn't check how many days are valid for a month)

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (dt text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values ('2017-13-01'),('2017-04-31'),('2017-04-33'),('2017-04-03'),('birth_date');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select str_to_date(dt,'%y-%m-%d') Invalid_year_format,
    -> str_to_date(dt,'%Y-%m-%d') Valid_year_format_MM_and_DD,
    -> datediff(now(),str_to_date(dt,'%Y-%m-%d')) datediff_examples
    -> from t;
+---------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| Invalid_year_format | Valid_year_format_MM_and_DD | datediff_examples |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| NULL                | NULL                        |              NULL |
| NULL                | 2017-04-31                  |                -6 |
| NULL                | NULL                        |              NULL |
| NULL                | 2017-04-03                  |                22 |
| NULL                | NULL                        |              NULL |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
5 rows in set, 11 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: getting still same output...even after correct `%Y-%m-%d` this

Comment: There is no difference if the table is myisam or innodb. As I said problem is with data not function.

Comment: i got the problem..there is mistake in my data. I just export a single row and its have `\0` with date and after `REPLACE` that i am able to perform date operations..thanks